# Java keeps locking up in program that gathers information from internet

Tags: java, freeze, urlconnection

I have a Java program that is gathering information from the internet.  It uses a BufferedReader and URLConnection to retrieve a csv file from Yahoo every 3 seconds.  Then it uses BufferedWriter to append a different CSV file with the data reformatted.

It will run successfully for 2-3 days most times, but it will just lock up for seemingly no reason.  Standard out just stops reporting any progress.

I thought I would fix it by just running it every day, but one out of 3-4 days it will fail in the middle of the day, at different times.  It is making about 8400 connections to the internet that total about 8 MB per day.

The code below is the code that reads the information off the internet.  This is inside a method that returns an object that holds an array of Strings to represent the ASCII file.

```
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String thisLine;
    try{
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream()));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error: " + e);
    }
    try{
        while((thisLine = br.readLine()) != null){
            lines.add(thisLine);
            size++;
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e){}
```

This is not a multi-threaded application.

So I have been thinking about what could be going wrong, and here are my guesses:

1. I did something wrong with the URLConnection to make it hang. (Everything I did in relation to URLConnection is in my coding)
2. I have some memory issue where I am using enough of my memory moving around that I have an error that is fatal to the program (this is run on a PC, not a server with ECC RAM).  I don't know the feasibility of this.
3. I synchronizing my data with calls to Calendar.  I don't know if calling Calendar 60 times a minute would have some ill effect on the JVM.
4. There is some instability with file locks and repeatedly appending a file that could lock the JVM (see code below)
5. I didn't close something that I didn't know to close.

The program stores the data and appends the output files every 30 seconds:

```
/**
 * Writes a file at the path denoted by fileName.  This will be an ASCII file.
 * @param fileName The path to write the file to
 */
public void appendFile(String fileName){
    try {
        //if()
        BufferedWriter b = Files.newBufferedWriter(new File(fileName).toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset(),StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            b.write(lines.get(i));
            b.newLine();
        }
        b.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Some other notes:

This program is running at top capability. I would like to collect data every second, but it cannot keep up.  This seems to be limited by the internet connection.

I am not having any memory issues.  If I watch my memory, there does not seem to be a leak.

The same thing happens whether I run as an application, run in Eclipse, or run as a System Task (Windows 7).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  All of those ideas above are just things I have been brainstorming, so if one of them seems really dumb, I understand.  Also, any recommendations for probing the issue would be great.  I have had some experience with the Eclipse debugger, but something like this, that hangs 6 hours after starting it (when I am at work) is kind of hard for me to probe.  I have never used the debugger successfully to assess a hangup, only an error that throws a RuntimeException, or by using a breakpoint.

Comment: I guess you know, that you should close your connections? Also think about using the [`try-with-resources` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: I will look into both of these.  Thanks so far; open to more suggestions.

Comment: @VasilisChados what's the meaning of _flushing a Reader_? It doesn't make sense to me. Besides `BufferedReader` has no `flush` method.  Flushing a `Writer` would make sense though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by launching the URLConnections in separate threads.  Then, if a connection hits an unresponsive server (or if there is any problem), the next thread is still fired.  It is not the most elegant solution, but it worked.

Each thread calls a data structure held by the main class, and drops the downloaded data there.  Then, the data is sorted and appended to a CSV file as it grows above a set point.  I plan to add some code, just in case it can help someone out.

I tried to set timeouts, but I was unsuccessful.  It would still lockup.  The real problem was that it fails once every 12 hours, and I run it for 8 hours at a time, so it is very hard to debug (it would take weeks, calendar time).  In any case, the threads solve any issue of delaying the following data point also, which timeouts would not have solved because I probably would have set the timeout to a longer time than the frequency that I retrieved data.

Answer (score 0):

It is neither locking up nor freezing. It is *blocking,* trying to read from an unresponsive server.

The cure to that is to set a read timeout on the `HttpURLConnection`, catch the resulting `SocketTimeoutException`, and deal with it appropriately, whatever that means for your application.

NB the code you posted should all be in a single `try/catch` structure. Code that depends in the success of code in a `try` block should be side that `try` block. And don't ignore exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents...

1. Are you closing BufferedReader? Its not seen on the code posted.
2. I guess 3s is too frequent for a Yahoo server to identify the automated request and block such requests, unless its an open API / you're authorized to perform such requests.